# Duration of animation is not changing in JQuery method

Tags: javascript, jquery, frontend

I wrote a couple of JS lines with JQuery, and the problem seems to appear on every object. I'm getting a element and try to animate it in different ways (fadeIn, toggleClass etc).

```
$("#menuElement").fadeIn(250);
```

But no matter what duration I use, it won't have an effect on the animation. The weird thing is, after couple of reloads it suddenly worked, but now it stopped working again. I also tried different browsers (Safari, Chrome, Firefox) and cleaned the cache and all.

Comment: Make sure you are writing above code in `document.ready` method. So that you have menuElement available when the code executes.

Comment: I included the script-tag at the end of the document, and the document.ready function is called at the end of the script as well. The methods themselves are working (like toggleClass). So the element itself is available, it just ignores the duration passed for the animation. FadeIn is also fading, but using the default duration.

Answer (score 0):

Check this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k9f53wpp/2/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#menuElement").fadeIn(250);
});
```

Comment: The method it self is executing. It just ignores the passed duration and uses default instead. The function is also not called on document.ready, it is triggered with onClick of another element

Answer (score 0):

Please check if your animations are turned off globally (jQuery.fx.off = true) which could be one reason why animations wouldn't work. Try adding a callback function to the fadeIn function and check if gets called after the animation is completed

Eg :

```
fadeIn(250,function(){
       alert("animation completed");
     });
```